# Transform scale effects

Tags: html, css

I have developed a website and on it I have some elements that have transform: scale(1.1) on hover.

The problem is that when applying the transform, the children elements look foggy and warped and I want them to look sharp and clear all the way through the animation.

The website is [this](http://www.pawpointer.com).

The elements that I'm talking about are the rectangle-shaped ones at the middle of the page, under 'Our breeder family'.

Answer (score 4):

So, as far as I know this is impossible the way you wish to do it, because `scale` is a graphical CSS property, so by increasing the size of an image it will by definition get less sharp. The only trick I could think of is making the default bigger and then having `transform: scale(.9091)` in it's non `:hover` state and `transform: scale(1)` in it's `:hover` state.

The other alternative is not to use `scale()` at all and instead scale manually by changing the size of the box and the font sizes inside it. Harder to make, more client intensive, but you get a lot more control in return.